# Using ArcPy to retrieve maps posted on an ArcGIS portal?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-portal, arcgis-python-api

I'm using ArcPy and python 3.5 to connect to a few different instances of ArcGIS portal.

The goal is to produce a report listing the maps, layers, and datasources that each portal instance has to compare differences between them.

My problem is, I can't figure out how to retrieve or list the maps from python.  I can connect to the portals and output the data from the GetPortalDescription function but I'm not sure where to go next.

```
import arcpy
import arcgis
import json
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from arcgis.gis import GIS

def parse_url(url):
    parsed_uri = urlparse( url)
    hostname=parsed_uri.hostname    
    return hostname

def output_portal(portalUrl, portalAdminUser, portalAdminUserPassword):
    #gis = GIS(portalUrl, portalAdminUser, portalAdminUserPassword)
    gis=GIS()
    url = arcpy.GetActivePortalURL()
    print("Current Portal: "+url)
    domain=parse_url(url)
    portalDesc =arcpy.GetPortalDescription()
    outfile=open(domain+".json","w")
    outfile.write(json.dumps(portalDesc, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
    outfile.close()
    # get all maps posted to the portal
    # for each map print all the layers in the portal
```

Comment: Post your code. You just need to search the content. Use the arcgis python api, not arcpy.

Comment: @BenSNadler  Done. I guess I was barking up the wrong tree. I thought I had to use arcpy to talk to the portal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the ArcGIS Python API from the [help](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/sample-notebooks/clone-portal-users-groups-and-content/#For-each-user-create-a-mapping-of-itemId-to-the-Item)

The output of this is a dictionary of all items (source_items_by_id).

Do with them as you wish:

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
source = GIS("https://host.esri.com/portal", "adminuser", "adminpassword")
# Query Portal for all users, ignore admin and system accounts
source_users = source.users.search('!esri_ & !admin')
source_items_by_id = {}
for user in source_users:
    num_items = 0
    num_folders = 0
    print("Collecting item ids for {}".format(user.username), end="\t\t")
    user_content = user.items()

# Get item ids from root folder first
for item in user_content:
    num_items += 1
    source_items_by_id[item.itemid] = item

# Get item ids from each of the folders next
folders = user.folders
for folder in folders:
    num_folders += 1
    folder_items = user.items(folder=folder['title'])
    for item in folder_items:
        num_items += 1
        source_items_by_id[item.itemid] = item

print("Number of folders {} # Number of items {}".format(str(num_folders), str(num_items)))
```